When exactly call operator on type object creates another type object?
I'm noob in python and trying to get some details. So I was reading Python Types and Objects by Shalabh Chaturvedi , when the whole small book made sense to me I encountered this para.

There are two kinds of objects in Python:

Type objects - can create instances, can be subclassed.

Non-type objects - cannot create instances, cannot be subclassed.


...
To create a new object using subclassing, we use the class statement and specify the
bases (and, optionally, the type) of the new object. This always creates a type object.
To create a new object using instantiation, we use the call operator (()) on the type object
we want to use. This may create a type or a non-type object, depending on which type
object was used.

last para with italicized text totally eluded me. I thought calling someTypeObject() always created instance of type object.
I Googled and tried ChatGPT but couldn't get proper answer

This whole thing could be rewritten more clearly. The only thing that can create a new instance is object.__new__; everything else ultimately delegates object creation to it. class statements do not always create a type; it depends on what metaclass is being used. (class X(metaclass=lambda *args: 3): pass, for example, produces the same result as X = 3.)

type is what they call a "type object", and type('NewType', (), {}) will create a new type (which is also an instance of type).

If it helps clarify, where it says "optionally, the type", that also means the metaclass.

When it's a metaclass. Normally that means type, the default metaclass for Python classes.

I thought calling someTypeObject() always created instance of type object.

You're correct. Calling type (with three arguments) creates an instance of type (i.e. a type object AKA a class).
Demo:
>>> type(type)  # `type` is an instance of itself
<class 'type'>
>>> type(object)  # types (classes) are instances of `type`
<class 'type'>
>>> T = type('TEST', (), {})  # Call returning a type object
>>> type(T)
<class 'type'>
>>> x = T()  # Call returning a non-type object
>>> type(x)
<class '__main__.TEST'>


Note that the one-argument form of type() is totally different: it returns the type of an object. Yes, it's confusing.

